# Why can't I draw on an image when I subclass UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to draw on an image from the camera roll using the code from [this tutorial](http://cocoabite.com/post/110000170154/smooth-drawing-in-swift). After selecting a photo from the camera roll, `imageView` is set to the photo. When the user presses the draw button, `tempImageView` is added over the photo, so the user can draw onto it. However, when I attempt to draw on the image, nothing happens. Why?

Code:

```
class EditViewController: UIViewController{
    var tempImageView: DrawableView!
    var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ClearImage"))

    func draw(sender: UIButton!) {
        tempImageView = DrawableView(frame: imageView.bounds)
        tempImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.view.addSubview(tempImageView)
    }

}

class DrawableView: UIView {

let path=UIBezierPath()
var previousPoint:CGPoint
var lineWidth:CGFloat=10.0

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    previousPoint=CGPoint.zero
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    previousPoint=CGPoint.zero
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let panGestureRecognizer=UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pan:")
    panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches=1
    self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    UIColor.greenColor().setStroke()
    path.stroke()
    path.lineWidth=lineWidth
}

func pan(panGestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer)->Void
{
    let currentPoint=panGestureRecognizer.locationInView(self)
    let midPoint=self.midPoint(previousPoint, p1: currentPoint)

    if panGestureRecognizer.state == .Began
    {
        path.moveToPoint(currentPoint)
    }
    else if panGestureRecognizer.state == .Changed
    {
        path.addQuadCurveToPoint(midPoint,controlPoint: previousPoint)
    }

    previousPoint=currentPoint
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

func midPoint(p0:CGPoint,p1:CGPoint)->CGPoint
{
    let x=(p0.x+p1.x)/2
    let y=(p0.y+p1.y)/2
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

}
```

Comment: Without trying it out myself: at least set the frame origin to (0,0) of the tempImageView in draw() (that is, don't use the parents bounds unchanged), and set the lineWidth before you stroke the path in drawRect()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that tempImageView.userIteractionEnabled = YES. by default this property for UIImageView is NO. 
after put breakpoint to you gestureRecogniser method, see if it's being called.